# PHP: jasperreports parameters

Tags: php, parameters, jasperserver

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction. I want to use the jasperreports server 6.3.0 to generate some reports by using PHP. In PHP I use the Jaspersoft PHP client 2.0 to generate the reports. This works fine but I have a problem with parameters.

This is how my JRXML looks like:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="305" y="42" width="100" height="30" uuid="5bbcd9d3-c70e-4b5c-8b0e-5948ce000cbd"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Parameter1}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I want to fill that Parameter with a value, what I tried is to use input controls but in the report the value is always null.

My PHP code is:

```
$c = new Client(
    "http://localhost:8080/jasperserver",
    "jasperadmin",
    "jasperadmin"
);
$controls = array(
    'Paramter1' => 'Hello World im Report!'
);
$report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/testreports/report1', 'pdf', null, null, $controls);
```

I assume that either

1. it is not possible to use input controls to achieve what I want
2. I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you very much for any helpful answers!

Comment: Could it be because you wrote in the php code `Paramter1` (missing *e*) instead of `Parameter1` as the report expects?

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wasted a couple of hours searching for that... Sometimes when its too easy it takes ages to find the problem :(

Comment: Yeah I know that feeling. But believe me - you will *never* do this mistake again :)